# Rails: un force_ssl (back from https to http)

Tags: http, https, ruby-on-rails-3.1, devise

I'm using force_ssl (Rails 3.1, specifically in the Devise config) to make sure that the user signs in on a secure page. But after that I'd like to switch back to http. How do I do that? In other words: how do your force non-ssl?

Note that i'm running on Heroku, so I cannot modify a http rewriter or something similar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you implement the code found in [this gist](https://gist.github.com/1040964) it should take care of the redirects back to http for you.

Comment: Chelsea, sorry for the late acknowledgement; I sort of worked my way around this, but that did only hold up until yesterday. It was only then that I saw your very helpful answer. Thanks for helping me out!